# Apply gradient (shading) background to algorithm listing

Tags: graphics, color, lyx, boxes, gradient

### Background

A number of source files are included within floating algorithm boxes. The source files are PNG images with a transparent background. The document is edited using LyX.

### Problem

The source code listings (algorithms) are applied to the document as follows:

```
% Change the background colour of algorithm boxes.
\let\oldalgorithm\algorithm
\let\endoldalgorithm\endalgorithm
\renewenvironment{algorithm}[1][htbp]{
  \let\graphicsformat\justifiedandcolored
  \oldalgorithm[#1]
}%
  {\endoldalgorithm}

% Change the background colour of the algorithm floats.
\def\justifiedandcolored#1{%
  \setlength\fboxrule{0pt}%
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
  \kern-1.35pt
  \colorbox{sourcecolour}{%
    \hbox to\linewidth{#1}%
  }%
  \par
  \kern-1.5pt
}
```

I would like to change the `colorbox` to a gradient (rather than a solid colour), using the `pst-grad` package or perhaps the `tikz` package.

All the examples I could find for `pst-grad` show how to apply a gradient to a box with known dimensions. In this situation, the width and height are unknown. The dimensions depend on:

1. The resolution of the image.
2. The scaling of the image (large images are scaled down to the page margins).

### Example

Here is a small source document:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 1.6.7 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[letterpaper,oneside,english,twoside,pointlessnumbers,obeyspaces,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels ]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[unicode=true, pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}

%% A simple dot to overcome graphicx limitations
\newcommand{\lyxdot}{.}

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{algorithm}{tbp}{loa}[chapter]
\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\input{example-preamble.tex}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\ding{233}}
  \def\labelitemii{\ding{219}}
  \def\labelitemiii{\normalfont\bfseries{--}}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\input{chapter.tex}


\chapter{Chapter}

%
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\includegraphics{source/sql/beautify-after\lyxdot sql}

\caption{\label{alg:After-Beautification}After Beautification}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Here is the example-preamble.tex:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[automark,nouppercase]{scrpage2}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}

% Use a hyphen for captions, and make links give a bit of space.
\captionsetup{hypcapspace=0.5\baselineskip}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,labelsep=endash}
\captionsetup[ruled]{labelfont=bf,labelsep=endash}

% Change algorithm to "Listing".
\floatname{algorithm}{Listing}
\newcommand{\algorithmname}{Listing}

% Colour definitions.
\input{colours.tex}

% Determine if the image is too wide for the page.
\makeatletter
\def\ScaleIfNeeded{%
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
  \else
    \Gin@nat@width
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% Resize figures that are too wide for the page.
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
  \graphicsformat{%
    \oldincludegraphics[width=\ScaleIfNeeded]{#2}%
  }%
}

% Centre graphics within non-Algorithm floats.
\let\graphicsformat\centering

% Change the background colour of algorithm boxes.
\let\oldalgorithm\algorithm
\let\endoldalgorithm\endalgorithm
\renewenvironment{algorithm}[1][htbp]{
  \let\graphicsformat\justifiedandcolored
  \oldalgorithm[#1]
}%
  {\endoldalgorithm}

% Change the background colour of the algorithm floats.
\def\justifiedandcolored#1{%
  \setlength\fboxrule{0pt}%
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
  \kern-1.35pt
  \colorbox{sourcecolour}{%
    \hbox to\linewidth{#1}%
  }%
  \par
  \kern-1.5pt
}

% Required by LyX...
\makeatletter
```

Example image:

[image]

Example PDF:

[image]

### Question

What is the best way to replace `colorbox` with a gradient?

### Ideas

One idea I had was to use ImageMagick on the image and add a gradient that way. If I decide to change the gradient colours, I'd have to regenerate dozens of source files. This solution would work, but is not ideal.

Thank you!

Comment: can you provide a complete small example?

Comment: ... with a picture uploaded somewhere that we can use.

Comment: From your description, it seems to me that putting the picture into a tikz node, like in this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz, except that you would draw the gradient under the picture rather than over it, may work for you.  I am not sure it will work with png images.  I am actually surprised that what you describe works for you, I thought that tex did not support transparency in png images.

Comment: Apparently, my information about tex not supporting transparency in png was outdated.  It works very nicely!

Comment: Dave, please always use the default "Add Image" interface to ensure that the images are here to stay. Your images seem to be broken because of the automatic URL replacement. See [How do we repair Gonzalo Medina's posts containing images?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1440/how-do-we-repair-gonzalo-medinas-posts-containing-images) for more information.

Comment: Why are the source files images rather than just text in a `listings` or `algorithm` environment?

Comment: `listings` or `algorithm` have insufficiently flexible syntax highlighting. See also: http://superuser.com/questions/213217/convert-html-to-image and the image response to the accepted answer. LaTeX could, with perhaps a year of my effort, produce the syntax highlighting in all the languages I needed. Or I could write a simple script to take gVim's HTML output and create an image to embed in only several hours' worth of effort.

Comment: @Dave Jarvis, I get "! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]." when I try to use your colored algorithm environment. Any suggestions?

Comment: @mangledorf: Ask a new question on here and show the full preamble that you're using.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `tikz` with the `backgrounds` library for this. You need to load `tikz` and the `backgrounds` library after the `xcolor` package, so this would have to be placed in your `example-preamble.tex`

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
```

In your `example-preamble.tex`, change the definition of `\justifiedandcolored` to this:

```
\def\justifiedandcolored#1{%
  \setlength\fboxrule{0pt}%
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
  \tikz[background rectangle/.style={top color=red!20,bottom color=white},
  tight background,
  show background rectangle] 
  \node [inner sep=0pt] (0,0) {#1};%
}
```

Which will yield the following output:

[image]